# What is the best solution for the ionic 5 and scroll content with fixed above part?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to scroll **ion-content** in the ionic 5 mobile application. I know how I can use **slot="fixed"** in **ion-content**. But it doesn't work as expected. Because a fixed part covers the scroll part in **ion-content** like as a standard fab button. I want to make the fixed and scroll part as a same level. No one covers the other one. What is the best solution in the ionic 5/Angular application? I don't like to use pure css styles like a web application. Prefer to use ionic components with ionic style variables.
Like this image
[Ionic Content Image with fixed and scroll parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0ov.png)

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use **ion-header**. So only scrolling part will be **ion-content**.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the fixed block outside ion-content, it should exclude it from scrollable area